# Font not changing in jar file

Tags: java, javafx, fonts, javafx-2, javafx-8

```
 Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("BankGothic Bold.TTF"),20);
title.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: ",titleSize.asString(),";","-fx-font-family: 'BankGothic Bold'"));
```

I am using the above code for my java fx application and it works in my intellij IDE. But the jar file still uses default font.

Comment: can you unzip the jar and see if the font is inside? perhaps whatever is packaging the jar isn't including it

Comment: Yes, the font is included there.

Comment: Do you get the same results when you try to change the font in fxml file?

Comment: I haven't used fxml.

Comment: Could you provide a file structure where do you have TTF file?